# Find common strings in two ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find common strings contained in two ranges. How do I use the intersection function to compare each cell in the range?

If tried just a simple intersection but it always says there is no intersection.

```
Sub MAIN()
    Set Rng1 = Range("L1:M1")
    Set Rng2 = Range("V2")
    Set intersec = Intersect(Rng1, Rng2)
    If Not intersec Is Nothing Then
        If intersec.Cells.Count = Rng2.Cells.Count Then
            'something
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If rng2 contained "a" and rng1 contained "a" and "b" then I want intersec to contain "a".

Comment: `Intersect` is where *ranges* intersect. `L1:M1` and `V2` don't overlap.

Comment: You can use Find or Match to see if a range contains a value.

Comment: Is there a way to compare the entire subset of values inside the ranges?

Comment: @johnrogeksu you can use a loop and `InStr` to check if the contained values are within the search array/cell.  This is in conjunction with match or find to obtain the column/row number.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Set rng1 = Range("L1:M1")
    Set rng2 = Range("V2")

    Set intersec = rng1.Find(rng2.Value)

    If Not intersec Is Nothing Then

            'something

    End If
End Sub
```

Find function will do the job for you